# When I load Pillow with pygame, I got an error: "ValueError: Unrecognized type of format"

Tags: python, image, pygame, python-imaging-library

I want to load a Pillow `Image` with Pygame. I converted a PNG image to a Python `bytes` object though `.tobytes()` and loaded it into Pygame with `pygame.image.fromstring()`.

This is my code:

```py
from PIL import Image
import pygame
image = Image.open("./QR/test.png")

image.show()
mode = image.mode
size = image.size
data = image.tobytes()

py_image = pygame.image.fromstring(data, size, mode)
```

My Python version is 3.7.5, Pillow version is 7.0.0, and Pygame version is 1.9.6.
I got an error in the last line:

`ValueError: Unrecognized type of format`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Pillow loads the image in greyscale mode, because it can, but then Pygame can’t recognise this. To fix it, you need to `convert()` the image to a format Pygame understands, by changing your third line to this:

```py
image = Image.open("./QR/test.png").convert("RGB")
```

If you need an alpha channel, change `"RGB"` to `"RGBA"`.

Note that if you don’t intend to use the image in Pillow, you can just use

```py
py_image = pygame.image.load("./QR/test.png")
```

which is much faster and shorter.